# MongoDB throwing BsonInvalidOperationException when accessing GridFS

Tags: java, mongodb, gridfs

This code:

```
ServerAddress serverAddress = new ServerAddress(url, Integer.valueOf(port));
MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createScramSha1Credential(username,"admin",
 password.toCharArray());
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(serverAddress, Arrays.asList(credential));
MongoDatabase mongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("admin");
GridFSBucket gridFSBucket = GridFSBuckets.create(mongoDatabase);
gridFSBucket.find().forEach(
 new Block < GridFSFile > () {
  @Override
  public void apply(final GridFSFile gridFSFile) {
   System.out.println(gridFSFile.getFilename());
  }
 });
```

Throws this error:

```
org.bson.BsonInvalidOperationException: Value expected to be of type DOCUMENT is of unexpected type NULL
    at org.bson.BsonValue.throwIfInvalidType(BsonValue.java:419)
    at org.bson.BsonValue.asDocument(BsonValue.java:47)
    at org.bson.BsonDocument.getDocument(BsonDocument.java:506)
```

I'm been puzzled with this, since using a MongoDB client (like Robomongo) I can see the *fs.files*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen the same problem when the "metadata" field was null. It seems that the `mongo-java-driver` throws an exception when the file's "metadata" field is null. However it should be optional (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/#files.metadata).

Check the other fields too. It can happen that you have a null value somewhere in the document.

There is a Jira issue for the "metadata"
(https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2577).

### UPDATE

Answer from https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2577: the `metadata` field should not be null.

### UPDATE 2

I found a solution with the old MongoDB API which is available in the 3.x drivers but it will be deprecated.

```
GridFS gridFs = new GridFS(client.getDB("genisys"), "fs");
gridFs.getFileList().forEach(f -> System.out.println(f.get("filename")));
```

Comment: Yeah, there are metadata that are null in the fs.files however I am dealing now with 137K files

Comment: Received an answer from the Java driver team. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I've found a way, check `UPDATE 2`!